# Vertex weights after Extrusion

Tags: rigging, extrude

I have a character, the character is rigged. However, it requires extrusion in forehead area, after rigging. In the N- Panel it also shows vertex weight of the newly extruded vertices. Although, when the character is switched to object mode, that white circled extruded portion disappeared (Screenshot attached).
Alternatively, the character can be rigged again but I want to learn procedures to extrude mesh after rigging.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: The vertices of the extrusion will inherit the weights of the original vertices that you've extruded, if you want to correct this weight you need to remove the weight and reassign, either in Weight Paint mode or with the Assign button under the vertex groups list